# How tall is SpaceX's launch mount in Boca Chica, TX

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, launchpad

SpaceX has a [render](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8JyvzU0CXU) of Starship launching from a tall launch mount. How tall is the launch mount not including the tower or launch hardware?

[image]

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but you're asking how tall something "is" that doesn't exist.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeah I get your point, but it does "exist" on a blueprint somewhere. I guess I should call SpaceX and simply ask them.

Comment: Considering that they're literally changing Starship on a weekly basis and haven't even started on Superheavy yet, I highly doubt that there are blueprints, and if there are, they are probably outdated by the time I finish writing this sentence. The image you posted seems already outdated, since the Starship is missing the "arm" flaps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Launch Mount render:

[image]

- [According to SpaceX](https://www.spacex.com/vehicles/starship/) the total height of Starship Super Heavy is 394 ft / 120 m
- [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship) the height of the Starship alone is 160 ft / 50 m

My measurements of the render: 181 pixels for Starship upper stage; 428 pixels for Starship Super Heavy; 110 pixels for launch mount.

The proportional height of the launch mount is very close to 100 ft / 30 m.